# How to implement a Queue using Linked List in C++ by classes only

Tags: c++, queue, singly-linked-list

I have a Linked List class, implemented like this (and tested too):

```
template <class T>
class LList {
    LNode<T>* head;
    LNode<T>* tail;
    int size; // proporciona muitas vantagens
    LNode<T>* rCopy(LNode<T>* right);
public:
    LList() : head(nullptr), tail(nullptr), size(0) {}
    LList(const LList& other) :
            head(nullptr), tail(nullptr), size(0) {
        *this = other;
    }
    ~LList() { clear(); }

...
    // O(1)
    void insertAtBack(T newvalue) {
        LNode<T>* tmp = new LNode<T>(newvalue, nullptr);
        tail->next = tmp;
        tail = tmp;
        if (head == nullptr)
            head = tmp;
        this->size++;
    }
...
};
```

Then, I created a Queue class:

```
template <class T>
class Queue {
private:
    LList<T> lista;
public:
//    Queue() : lista() {} ??? don't know how to do it
    void enqueue(T element);
    T peek();
    void dequeue();
    int size();
    bool isEmpty();
    void sizeLog();
};

template<class T>
void Queue<T>::enqueue(T element) {
    lista.insertAtBack(element);
}
```

But I can't use it on main, any attempt to enqueue causes crashing in the for loop, that returns error code -1073741819. The function `isEmpty()` works and displays `true`.

```
Queue<int> f;
std::cout << "created" << endl;
std::cout << f.isEmpty() << endl;

for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
    f.enqueue(i*5);
}
```

Output:

```
created
1

Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)
```

I've tried to write a constructor for Queue class to initialize the LList class, but can't find the right way to do it. If I write a main function to test only the LList class, I have no need for initialization, because its construtor already carries on with the job.

Comment: can you add the function definition for Queue::enqueue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initially the `tail, head` are `nullptr` so when the first element is inserted, you attempt to access `tail->next` in `insertAtBack` where `tail` is `nullptr` causing the error (probably an uncaught exception), if the `tail` is `nullptr`, simply assign it the `tmp` value. place a `nullptr` check for the expression like so..

```
// O(1)
    void insertAtBack(T newvalue) {
        LNode<T>* tmp = new LNode<T>(newvalue, nullptr);

        // if it is nullptr, 
        // it is the first and only element
        // so head = tail = tmp
        if(tail != nullptr) 
            tail->next = tmp;
        tail = tmp;
        if (head == nullptr)
            head = tmp;
        this->size++;
    }

``
```

Comment: I miss a simple test: `if (tail != nullptr)` , sorry, I was focused on the constructor.